# Can I create a `pytest.mark.failif`?

Tags: python, pytest

`pytest` allows you to skip a test under some condition (i.e.: on a platform):

```py
@pytest.mark.skipif(sys.platform == "win32")
def test_foo(fixture):
    assert bar(fixture)
```

Is there a way to create a mark to make the test *fail* under a certain condition?

```py
@pytest.mark.failif(sys.platform == "win32")
def test_foo(fixture):
    assert bar(fixture)
```

Comment: do you mean `xfail`? or do you want it to create a test failure -- you could always do `assert sys.platform != 'win32'`

Comment: @AnthonySottile No, I do not mean `xfail`. And yeah, I know I could put an assertion inside the function. I just wonder if it is possible to do it. If so, I would like to learn how. ^^

Comment: That is a weird requirement. Why would you want to mark a test failure?

Comment: @wim I found a project using a decorator to mark test failures. This decorator does not allow using fixtures though. Answering this question would allow the use of fixtures in tests while, at the same time, avoid entering into discussions to try to change the way they are used to write their tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even without pytest you could write a simple decorator that does this:

```py
def failif(condition: bool, *, reason: str) -> Callable[[T], T]:
    def failif_decorator(func: T) -> T:
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def failif_decorator_inner(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
            assert not condition, reason
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return cast(T, failif_decorator_inner)
    return failif_decorator
```

Usage would be

```py
@failif(sys.platform == 'win32', reason='we do not support windows')
def test():
    ...
```

for a pytest-specific solution you could use one of the [hooks for registering marks](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html#passing-a-callable-to-custom-markers) -- though that's quite a bit more involved

Comment: ah I left out the PEP 484 `typing` imports (and the `T = TypeVar('T')`) -- they're not necessary (the `cast` call can be replaced with just `return failif_decorator_inner`)